# Get product by attribute value

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute

Is there a way to get all products by a specific attribute value? For example: how can I get all the products where the attribute color is red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use below code**

```
class GetProducts{
  protected $_productRepository;

  protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
   ) {
     $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
     $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
   }

public function getProductCollection(){
  $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('color', 4, 'eq')->create(); // 4 is the option id, may be red/green/blue, check in admin
  $searchResults = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
  $productsIds = $searchResults->getItems();
  return $productsIds;
}
```

**Hope this may help you**

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @StijnDR, Thanks for accepting!!